# .visible? is returning true when it should be false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dom, attributes, capybara

In a rails app, I have the following css

```
#step2 { display:none }
```

My test for this condition is here

```
Then /^I should not see "([^\"]*)" because it is hidden$/ do |id|
  s=page.find(id)
  expect(s.visible?).to be false
end
```

When I bring up the page manually, the section is not visible.

The error is

```
  expected true
       got false
   (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/navagation_steps.rb:85:in `/^I should not see "([^\"]*)" because it is hidden$/'
  features/profile.feature:10:in `And I should not see "#step2" because it is hidden'
```

The page.find call does seem to work properly. If I print the object I get

```
#<Capybara::Node::Element:0x007fd42ea30818>
```

I have tried all sorts of different incantations to no avail.  This seems the most straightforward.  Does anyone see the problem here?  It has me stumped.

Comment: try `expect(s.visible?).to be_falsey` ..

Comment: What driver are you using with capybara for these tests?

Comment: Shows you what a newbie I am. I have no idea what the driver is. How do you determine that?

Answer (score 0):

expect(s.visible?).not_to be eq(true)

This seems to work.

Comment: did you try mine ? What I said will work, because your expectation was wrong.

Comment: Yes I tried it and it didn't work for me.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Using the dynamic predicate matchers provided by RSpec will read better and give better error messages

```
expect(s).not_to be_visible
```

Note - if you're using the default rack-test driver with Capybara it doesn't process most "external" CSS so it won't be able to determine visibility unless display: none is in the elements style attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned method, if you are verifying the the element is not visible on page

```
Then /^I should not see "([^\"]*)" because it is hidden$/ do |id|
  expect(page).to have_selector(<SELECTOR>,:visible => false)
end
```

Or you can also do same like

```
Then /^I should not see "([^\"]*)" because it is hidden$/ do |id|
  page.find(<SELECTOR>, :visible => false)
end
```

**Note:** `<SELECTOR>` is a css selector of an element.

Hope this helps :)